# Can't find my user on my custom instance on search in mastodon

Tags: federation, mastodon, activitypub, webfinger

here is the implementation of webfinger I did https://wildleague.org/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:ropoko@wildleague.org

why I can't find this user on searching in mastodon?

I tried changing some fields, like followers, id, url, that I thought could be required ones, but it didnt work.

Also, when I see logs on my server, it returns status 200 and the json format is ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo on the `subject` field